# python mongodb regex: ignore case

Tags: python, regex, mongodb

How can I specify a REGEX and ignore the case:

```
regex = ".*" + filter + ".*";
config.gThingCollection.find({"name":{"$regex":regex}})
```

I want the filter to be case-insensitive, how to achieve that?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try using the python regex objects instead. Pymongo will serialize them properly:

```
import re
config.gThingCollection.find({"name": re.compile(regex, re.IGNORECASE)})
```

Answer (score 26):

You can use MongoDB regex options in your query, something like this:

```
config.gThingCollection.find({"name":{"$regex":regex, "$options": "i"}})
```

Answer (score 4):

```
res = posts.find({"geography": {"$regex": 'europe', "$options": 'i'}})

# if you need use $not
import re
res = posts.find(
    {"geography": {"$not": re.compile('europe'), "$options": 'i'}})
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code should look like this:

```
regex = ".*" + filter + ".*";
config.gThingCollection.find({"name":{"$regex":regex, "$options":"i"}})
```

Reference: http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/operator/regex/